# How can I select the value and type of a dynamic list?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, dynamic-linq

I have a dynamic query that brings me dynamic columns (`System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`):

```
var data = data.Select("new (col1, col2, col3)", "T", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

```
[
   { col1: "This", col2: 1.56, col3: "Something else" }
]
```

Now I need to bring the type of each column. ex:

```
[
   {
      col1: { value: "This", type: "string" },
      col2: { value: 1.56, type: "decimal" }
   }
]
```

To get that, I was thinking of something like:

```
var rows = data.Select(x => new {
    Type = MyHelper.GetType(x),
    Value = x
});
```

But that it's not working.

> An unhandled error occurred The best overloaded method match for
>   'MyHelper.GetType(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)' has some invalid
>   arguments

I do know how to get the type

```
public static string GetType(PropertyInfo type)
{
    return type.PropertyType.IsGenericType && type.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? type.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].ToString().Replace("System.", "") : type.PropertyType.Name;
}
```

But I don't know how to build the query.

[UPDATE]

This is a try, but not what I need

```
var rows = data.Select(x => new {
    Type = MyHelper.GetType(x.GetType()),
    Value = x
});
```

```
[
    {
        "type": "<>f__AnonymousType0`3",
        "value": {
            "col1": "2019-10-15T00:00:00",
            "col2": 0.00,
            "col3": "abc"
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: What is not working, and what do you get from `MyHelper.GetType(x)`?

Comment: @SelimYıldız, see the update

Comment: If I try ```x.GetValue(x, null)``` I get ```An unhandled error occurred Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference```

Comment: I have added an answer, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo you could refer to:

```
public List<object> Get(int id)
{
    var data = new List<Object>
    {
        new{
            col1="aaa",
            col2= 1.25,
            col3 = 1
        },
        new{
            col2="asd",
            col3= 1.2,
            col4 =2
        }

    };
    var aaa = new List<object>() { };
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        var ds = item.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach(var i in ds)
        {
            var name = i.Name;
            var type = i.PropertyType.Name;
            var value = item.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(item);
            aaa.Add(new  { name=name, type = type, value = value });

        }                
    }
    return aaa;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason it's been add a last element and giving an exception `Parameter count mismatch.`. The item it's `{ "name": "Item", "type": "Object" }`, maybe because of `.ToDynamicList()`. Anyway putting that on trycatch did solve the problem.